# Free Record / Replay solution for j2ee EJB layer

Tags: java, testing, jakarta-ee, ejb, web-testing

I'm looking for a free (if possible) solution where:

- You can **'record'** all the kinds of objects created during normal (production-like) usage of a webapp on an EJB application server (like Weblogic).
- Afterwards you can **'replay'** each page *separately* on an non-EJB application server like Tomcat.

Moreover, it would be fantastic if:

- One could easily **create test-suites** from all the recorded scenarios and replay them in different browsers (to test regressions).
- One could **modify or substitute single recorded objects**  (for example changing the fields of a map etc.) Changed objects can be saved and added into a test suite.

  It would be possible to **integrate the solution with an IDE**, optimally Eclipse.

I've tried googling and I've found  [Replay Solutions](http://www.replaysolutions.com/) . Their product seems to be pretty well-suited to my requirements but 
unfortunately it is paid and they don't even put pricing directly on the webpage (it's available after contacting the company).

Does anybody know such a solution or am I demanding too much?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you really need, but if you are looking for an UI testing suite you could give Selenium a try. It offers you a tool for firefox to record actions you actually do in the browser and generate java code from that, which will actually "replay" what you did before.